# Best way to download and install Eclipse if you want to do C++ and Java and GUI design

Tags: eclipse

I'm interested in using Eclipse. The [Eclipse Downloads page](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) has versions for Java Developers for Java EE Developers for C/C++ developers, and so on. I want to use Eclipse for Java, C/C++, GUI design, and more. There doesn't seem to be a single download that has it all. Am I missing something? Or is there an easy way to download and install all of the components.

And then it's a big pain every time they upgrade, as I have to do it all over again, and it seems that I have to do it again for every machine. Can I simply move the Eclipse folder form one machine to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every package available in the Downloads page is simply a package that bundles Eclipse with a set of plugins that intend to achieve the wanted goal.

Just choose a package (or begin from scratch with Eclipse Classic), and use the integrated update manager to install the plugins that you want.

And yes, moving your installation of Eclipse from one machine to another works.

**EDIT**: Here is a screenshot of what the update menu looks like. (Help/Install new Software…)
http://img375.imageshack.us/img375/8932/eclipsedownloadmenu.png

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I know you can add them, but my confusion is that the categories on the downloads page is not reflected in check-box interface. Instead there are all of these silly names like mylyn and wst.xml_ui that aren't very clear as to what they actually do.

Comment: I am not sure where you are getting the silly names problem - in my version of Eclipse I am getting names that are quite clear.

Comment: Those are the names that appear at http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/heliossr1, for example.

Comment: Ah, of course. In the downloads details (after you have selected packages), you will have a recapitulative of the package names that you have selected - at that moment you will be able to see the symbolic package names.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, if you want to browse Eclipse plugins by category, resolve plugin dependencies, and download the complete plugin-included Eclipse package as a single .zip, you can use Yoxos.

http://eclipsesource.com/en/yoxos/